# How to export one shapefile per shape in shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, export

I have road shapefile consists of Road No. Suppose i have a road network consisting of 125 roads. I need to get 125 individual shapefiles from one road network shapefile without select one by one. Is it possible to do?

Comment: With ArcPy it is easy - what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo, the accepted answer points to the GME tools which will do what the OP asks.  Splitting by OBJECTID would be the way to go.  I'm voting to keep it closed.

Comment: @Fezter You are right (as is Dan Patterson's answer) - I was too distracted by Split being used as part of a tool name that leaves features intact instead of splitting them - so I have deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Split layer by attributes](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=15ca63aebb4647a4b07bc94f3d051da5) using the FID field for your splitting